# JDBC, reading a prepared statement, only getting one field

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, struts2

How can I display other details of my profile? I'm using a session. I am only able to display the first name.

action class:

```
public String execute() throws Exception,SQLException{  
    if(User.validate(fname, pass)){  
        sessionmap.put("a",fname);
        sessionmap.put("b",lname);
        return "success";  
    }
```

dao :

```
public static boolean validate(String fname,String pass) throws Exception{
    boolean status=false;
    try {
        String sql=   "select * from user where fname=? and pass=? ";
        PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, fname);
        ps.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        status=rs.next();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
    return status;
}
```

jsp page:

```
<s:property value="#session.a" /> <s:property value="lname" />
```

Comment: `<s:property value="#session.b" />`. Before that u need to set it in session `sessionmap.put("b",lname);`.

Comment: You put it into the session map as `b` and try to display it as `lname`, using two different forms of expression...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24790578/573032